# Cocoa Applications Examples

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I've been doing some cocoa since a week, and I'm getting kinda good with it.

I did some tutorials, calculators, currency converter, etc...

But I was wondering if there was any more advanced guide? Like build a RSS reader, or anything else... I dunno..

If you know any good resource for examples please tell me.

PS: I'm reading some cocoa books, and I'm learning from several sources like cocoa dev central, etc..

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cocoa examples at the apple developers connection are extensive and an excellent resource. Find them [here](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of finding targeted example applications is from the Xcode documentation. Pick a class, for example NSTableView, and see what the related sample code shows;

Might be a better way than just picking examples at random.